# Are there relays for 5VDC?

Tags: relay, dc

I am trying to control a custom made LED strip remotely. I already have an RC power pack with an output of 5V, but it only provides power as long as I hold the buttons on the controller.

I was thinking to use it to control a relay and use another power source for the LEDs.

I am, however, having trouble finding the right component (also because I recently moved to France and I am not sure of the names.) I saw some relays on Amazon but according to the comments they need a constant signal to keep it on, which is what I already have.

Can someone tell me if there are relays available to control DC currents and what are they called?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is a "latch relay" (or "two-state relay"). I have used in the past the ones I attach (Omron G6J); then Fujitsu does very similar ones.[image]

This model carries up to 1 A, but you can parallel the two output contacts. Then, the maximum dc voltage is 110V, so at lower voltage you have some room for "a little bit of more current": speaking more quantitatively it is a matter of life expectancy at the switched voltage and switched current, as shown here below. Of course, Omron does not go beyond the said 1 A, but you understand that you have some small margin.[image]

Note. As already said on this site, I would avoid Amazon for such things, unless you have studied before the problem, you have a datasheet and you know exactly what you want.